# How to make vbscript hold down a Sendkey?

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

I want to be able to hold down a key for example hold down `ctrl` while i use `Sendkeys` to press `a`. Here is the simplified code(without all the useless stuff). I know that the answer im looking for is somewhere but I just can't find it with anyone with it working like I want

```
set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

ws.run "Teams.txt"

[script to make it hold ctrl]
ws.Sendkeys "a"
[script to make it hold ctrl]
ws.Sendkeys "c"

 ...

[script to make it hold ctrl]
ws.Sendkeys "v"
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

> To send keyboard characters that are comprised of a regular keystroke
>   in combination with a SHIFT, CTRL, or ALT, create a compound string
>   argument that represents the keystroke combination. You do this by
>   preceding the regular keystroke with one or more of the following
>   special characters:
>
> Key: Special Character
>
> SHIFT: +
>  CTRL: ^
>  ALT: %

Append a caret:

```
ws.Sendkeys "^c"
```

Comment: yes but how do i make sure it is constantly being pressed not being pressed once. but thanks this is helpful

Comment: Send it with each of the keystrokes:  `ws.Sendkeys "^a^c^v"`